# Cannot insert records into Apache Ignite cache from Apache Spark RDD

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, caching, ignite

I am trying to perform a simple insert to an Ignite cache (version 2.2) from a Spark application, using the code below (in scala):

```
val addresses=new util.ArrayList[String]()
addresses.add("127.0.0.1:48500..48520")

// IGNITE CONTEXT CONFIGURATIONS
 val igniteContext:IgniteContext=new IgniteContext(sc,()=>new IgniteConfiguration()
  .setDiscoverySpi(new TcpDiscoverySpi().
    setLocalPort(48511).setLocalPortRange(20).setIpFinder(new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder().setAddresses(addresses))),true)

// CHECKING IF Spark CACHE IS PRESENT
   println(igniteContext.ignite().cacheNames())
// RETURNS [Spark]

// FETCHING THE SPARK CACHE
val ignite_cache_rdd:IgniteRDD[String,Custom_Class] =igniteContext.fromCache[String,Custom_Class]("Spark")

  // SAVING PAIR_RDD TO CACHE
  ignite_cache_rdd.savePairs(ignite_PairRDD)

  //  PRINTING CONTENTS FROM CACHE
  ignite_cache_rdd.sql("select * from Custom_Class").show(truncate = false)
  //RETURNS AN EMPTY DATAFRAME
```

The contents of the ignite_PairRDD value field, when converted to a Dataframe, show up with no issue:

```
+-+-+-+
A |B |C|  
--------
22|6 |7|
+-+-+-+
```

The problem is after using "savePairs" and doing a "show()", the Ignite cache seems to be empty.

```
+-+-+-+
A |B |C|  
--------
  |  | |
+-+-+-+
```

The "Spark" cache has the following configurations (in java):

```
 CacheConfiguration cache_conf=new CacheConfiguration<String,Custom_Class>().setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED).setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC).setBackups(1).
            setIndexedTypes(String.class,Custom_Class.class).setName("Spark");
```

The "Custom_Class" is created using the following structure:

```
public class Equity_Data implements Serializable {
  @QuerySqlField(index = true)
  private A;

  @QuerySqlField(index = true)
  private B;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
  private C;
}
```

I made sure to check if the cache exists, and the SQL query seems to be correct because I do not get any errors, just an empty dataframe.

Do I need to change some configuration?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please share an example that can be run locally?

Comment: I would suggest creating a small reproducer project and sending it to Apache Ignite user mailing list: https://ignite.apache.org/community/resources.html#mail-lists